# will this installation succeed? if yes, will this failure make trouble to my system?

Tags: arch-linux

now i am trying to install archlinux's base system, the following are output to console:)

```
:: Retrieving packages from core...
 linux-api-headers-3.5.1-1-i686                                       607.7 KiB  58.1K/s 00:10 [#######################################################] 100%
error: failed retrieving file 'glibc-2.16.0-3-i686.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.us.leaseweb.net : Operation too slow. Less than 1024 bytes/sec transferred the last 10 seconds
 glibc-2.16.0-3-i686                                                    7.8 MiB  41.0K/s 03:14 [#######################################################] 100%
 bash-4.2.037-1-i686                                                  774.9 KiB  57.7K/s 00:13 [#######################################################] 100%
 bzip2-1.0.6-4-i686                                                    54.4 KiB  39.1K/s 00:01 [#######################################################] 100%
 coreutils-8.17-3-i686                                                  2.0 MiB  52.4K/s 00:40 [#######################################################] 100%
 cronie-1.4.8-3-i686                                                   56.0 KiB  27.3K/s 00:02 [#######################################################] 100%
 device-mapper-2.02.97-1-i686                                         150.4 KiB  38.2K/s 00:04 [#######################################################] 100%
error: failed retrieving file 'util-linux-2.21.2-5-i686.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.us.leaseweb.net : Operation too slow. Less than 1024 bytes/sec transferred the last 10 seconds
 util-linux-2.21.2-5-i686                                            1424.9 KiB  28.9K/s 00:49 [#######################################################] 100%
 cryptsetup-1.5.0-2-i686                                              155.1 KiB  58.5K/s 00:03 [#######################################################] 100%
 dhcpcd-5.6.0-1-i686                                                   71.4 KiB  42.3K/s 00:02 [#######################################################] 100%
 diffutils-3.2-1-i686                                                 216.4 KiB  43.9K/s 00:05 [#######################################################] 100%
 e2fsprogs-1.42.5-1-i686                                              752.0 KiB  48.4K/s 00:16 [#######################################################] 100%
 file-5.11-1-i686                                                     213.1 KiB  44.3K/s 00:05 [#######################################################] 100%
 filesystem-2012.7-1-any                                                3.7 KiB  4.62M/s 00:00 [#######################################################] 100%
 findutils-4.4.2-4-i686                                               336.2 KiB  43.6K/s 00:08 [#######################################################] 100%
 gawk-4.0.1-1-i686                                                    762.2 KiB  52.2K/s 00:15 [#######################################################] 100%
 gcc-libs-4.7.1-6-i686                                                811.8 KiB  47.9K/s 00:17 [#######################################################] 100%
 gettext-0.18.1.1-4-i686                                                4.9 MiB  54.7K/s 01:33 [#######################################################] 100%
 grep-2.14-1-i686                                                     191.7 KiB  43.2K/s 00:04 [#######################################################] 100%
 gzip-1.5-1-i686                                                       72.3 KiB  35.0K/s 00:02 [#######################################################] 100%
 heirloom-mailx-12.5-3-i686                                           197.1 KiB  34.5K/s 00:06 [#######################################################] 100%
 inetutils-1.9.1-3-i686                                               234.2 KiB  41.8K/s 00:06 [#######################################################] 100%
 sysvinit-2.88-6-i686                                                  76.0 KiB  39.8K/s 00:02 [#######################################################] 100%
 initscripts-2012.08.2-1-any                                           23.6 KiB  25.8K/s 00:01 [#######################################################] 100%
 sysfsutils-2.1.0-8-i686                                               29.5 KiB  23.0K/s 00:01 [#######################################################] 100%
 iputils-20101006-4-i686                                               65.1 KiB  30.1K/s 00:02 [#######################################################] 100%
 jfsutils-1.1.15-3-i686                                               169.1 KiB  32.4K/s 00:05 [#######################################################] 100%
 less-444-3-i686                                                       87.4 KiB  32.8K/s 00:03 [#######################################################] 100%
 licenses-2.9-1-any                                                    59.4 KiB  28.7K/s 00:02 [#######################################################] 100%
error: failed retrieving file 'linux-3.4.9-1-i686.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.us.leaseweb.net : Operation too slow. Less than 1024 bytes/sec transferred the last 10 seconds
```

from the output above, we see there are lots of failures:(

such as error: failed retrieving file xxx' from mirror.us.leaseweb.net : Operation too slow. Less than 1024 bytes/sec transferred the last 10 seconds

my question is will this installation succeed? if yes, will this failure make trouble to my system?

Answer (score 2):

The installer is able to download the packages from different sites (called mirrors).

When a download fails (or is too slow) it tries the next one but gives you a warning (to inform you so that you can for example remove the slow site from the mirrors list).

If you look at `glibc`: the installed tried to download it from `mirror.us.leaseweb.net` noticed that the download was to slow and then tried with success with another mirror.

```
 glibc-2.16.0-3-i686    7.8 MiB  41.0K/s 03:14 [#######################################################] 100%
```

Comment: should i delete mirror.us.leaseweb.net?

Comment: You can tune the mirror's list but as the system is able to choose the best one you can also use the default settings.

Comment: `pacman` is not able to choose the best one – it just tries mirrors from the top of the list to bottom, so it almost always uses the 1st one.

Comment: And though unstated, all packages are (attempted) downloaded before the group are installed. If a package wasn't successfully downloaded, you won't try to install any. Your computer will be usable, just like before you tried the update.

Answer (score 2):

Arch has a tool called reflector, installable through pacman, that can sort out and tune your mirrorlist.

Just grab reflector: pacman -S reflector

Then run: reflector --verbose -l 5 --sort rate --save /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

Wherein 5 is the number of mirrors you want in your list. I always have 6.

Comment: I'm an Arch user too and that's one thing I didn't know of, never needed it though; but it's always good to know.